# Scroll Bar is not working in DataGrid of UWA widget

Tags: javascript, html, css, frontend, widget

```
          var dataGrid = new UWA.Controls.DataGrid({
            className: "table",
            columns: result,
            data: e.Items,
            sortable: `true`,
          }).inject(widget.body);

          var myScroller = new UWA.Controls.Scroller(dataGrid, {
            height: 50,
            width:100,
            bounce: true,
            scrollableY:true,
            scrollableX:true,
            scrollbarH:true,
            scrollbarV:true,
            scrollDrag:true,
            events: {
              onScrollStart: function () {
                dataGrid.setStyle("background-color", "blue");
              },
            },
          });
```

I am trying to add a scrollbar in the UWA DataGrid
And **I am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': parameter 1 is not of type 'Node'.**